# Lottery number frequency (example only) analysis via Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to analyse Lottery number (Other examples exist for similar problem) using Excel meeting the requirements below:

1. want to find out the frequency of each number,
2. ability to filter it for Wed, Sat, and both via column DayofWeek
3. Keeping the source format. That is, all columns cannot be changed, like below:
4. More columns, e.g. draw machine name for each draw, can be added for filtering, similar to DayOfWeek.

**Data source**

```
DayofWeek   Ball 1  Ball 2  Ball 3  Ball 4  Ball 5  Ball 6  Bonus Ball
Wed         5       15     59       51      33      47      7
Sat        48       23     16       39      15      59      36
Wed        13       25     2        39      32      37      48
Sat        12       10     56       18      34      52      50
```

**Results**

```
DayofWeekFilterDropdownList(Wed,Sat,All)

Balls of 1-59   Frequency
1               2
2               3
3               4
... 
58              8
59              4
```

`Frequency()` can be used for part of the requirement, but I cannot generate the `DayOfWeekFilter`, which might be helped by `Pivot` table. Still, I cannot produce it.

Pivot table is more powerful, but I am new to it.

Comment: I hope that you are doing this for fun rather than for the irrational idea that you can increase your odds by detecting patterns in past results.

Comment: Lottery is just an example, which I forgot to mention it on the post. There are other examples in real life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF($J$1="All",COUNTIF($B$2:$H$5,J2),SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX(($A$2:$A$5=$J$1)*$B$2:$H$5,)=J2)))
```

[image]

All does a simple COUNTIF.

While Wed/Sat iterates through the columns to find the correct rows and values to return a count.

EDIT: Found a shorter formula.

Comment: it works. Thanks. Initially I was expecting a Pivot solution.I can produce the result for Sat using the formula with minor replacement.

Comment: @Pingpong well maybe someone smarter than me may still suggest one.  If that happens feel free to change the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `countifs` statement to count the frequency of balls occurring where the day is equal to Wed and Fri separately? You can then combine them to get the total frequency again. A tutorial is available on their use here: https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic

Comment: Is it possible to use Pivot table?

Comment: The best I can suggest (my Pivot knowledge is lacking unfortunately) would be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421773/using-an-or-condition-to-filter-an-excel-pivot-table
Hopefully someone else will be able to give a better answer though if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Scott's formula is great. Once you have the frequencies for each ball number based on day, create a table range like this (I'm using fake totals and only going 1-10 to show the effect):

[image: Picture 1]

If you still want to see how this data could work once in a pivot table, I simply added the delimiter "Day" to the range to allow for filtering later on.

Select the range and click "insert" - "pivot table" and build the table like this

[image: Picture 2]

The result is this:

[image: Picture 3]

You can now sort by wed, sat, or all using the drop down filter.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that most lotteries use different ball sets each day. Ohio has 4 ball sets for the rolling cash five. Not sure how many they have for the pick 3,4 and 5. But they choose randomly each day. But if you can find two particular days for a few weeks hitting a a certain number or numbers more often. Just maybe those two days for that week were using the same ball set and it continued each week for a few weeks. This would take some serious patience. Then when betting..which two days do you make your bets. I guess you would just have to bet every day and hope two days stick out.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question... The question is very straightforward and technical. A way to analyze data in a certain way. Don't know how you got to a more philosophical approach